# 'Error: Unexpected request' during Karma Angular Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

When running `grunt karma`, a test on one of the directive fails when it tries to fetch the template. I am using ng-html2js as a preprocessor. Here is some of my karma.conf.js

```
plugins: ['karma-chrome-launcher',
          'karma-jasmine',
          'ng-html2js',
          'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'],

preprocessors: {
  'app/scripts/directives/**/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  moduleName: 'templates'
}
```

In my test, I have the following:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: myDirective', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  var element,
    scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it('should not show search area initially', inject(function ($compile) {
    element = angular.element('<navbar></navbar>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(element.find('.myClass').hasClass('myClass')).toBe(true);
  }));
});
```

When I run the test, I get

`Error: Unexpected request: GET /scripts/directives/myDirective/myDirective.html`

It seems like the preprocessor is not properly injecting the javascript version of the template.

I have also tried using the path of the template in the `beforeEach(module(''));` but that causes an error that reads:

`Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module...`

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had kind of the same problem. Be sure you have the exact file match. Open the Google chrome console and check the file path is exactly the same.

[image]

In the upper exemple, I had to add a "/" string in ngHtml2JsPreprocessor.stripPrefix and it worked.
So I guess with Yeoman, you should use

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  moduleName: 'templates',
  stripPrefix: 'app/' //add a slash
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using the Yeoman tool to scaffold my project, I needed to add a `stripPrefix` to the `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor` option in my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  moduleName: 'templates',
  stripPrefix: 'app'
}
```